# Android TV ADT-1 adb connect port changed?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-tv

Hi as of yesterday I was able to build and push apk files to the ADT-1 Android TV device via WiFi. Then the device had an update and now I'm no longer able to connect to the device. I think the port number adb is allowed to connect on has changed... but to what?

Yes I've made sure the IP address is valid and am using the port number `4321`. Pinging the device works. But its giving me the error:

> unable to connect to 10.0.0.86:4321:4321

I've tried to connect via ethernet and WiFi.  Both fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I directly hooked it up to a laptop and manually forced it to use port 4321 again via: "adb tcpip 4321"

Now I can connect with my main dev computer from across the room again.

Comment: Great to hear. It would have been nice to understand to which port it changed.

Comment: Is there a "adb" option to get back the current port number?  So odd this changed and didn't even change to the default Android one.

Comment: I don't have a convenient way to connect via USB to do this. Has anyone figured out the new port number?

Comment: I don't think there's a new port number. I wrote a script that attempts to connect to every port in the range and it did find a valid port number to connect to.

Comment: Directly connected with what?  There is no usb on ADT-1

Comment: Yes there is.  Its a special cord that comes with the device that converts micro usb to usb.  Just like any Android device but a little different.

Answer (score 3):

Grumpf. Look like they removed the necessary "service.adb.tcp.port=4321" from build.prop in 5.0.2.

Why, oh why?

Comment: I tried editing build.prop to put back the line that's been removed, but ended up bricking the ADT-1.  I think the text editor I was using corrupted the build.prop file.  I got it working again by manually flashing back to the stock image, but is there a permanent way to add-back this setting so every time I reboot the ADT-1 I don't have to reset the tcpip port to 4321?